# Require and extend classes in Electron, how to?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, electron

I have a file `global.js` that contains

```
var Global = (function () {
    function Global() {
        this.greeting = 'test';
    }

    Global.prototype.getList = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Global;
})();
```

and another file 'main.js', that contains

```
var global= new Global();

console.log(global.getList);
```

then i require them in the index.html

```
...
<script>
    require('./npmMain.js');
    require('./main.js');
</script>
```

and i get `Global is not defined`

How can i make the class available to main.js?

Any ideas?

edit: if i `console.log('test');` inside `npmMain.js` i can see it run, so the file is getting required, just that class is not available or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of modules!

First, inside of your `main.js` file, add a line at the top like this:

```
var Global = require('./npmMain.js').Global;
```

Then at the end of `npmMain.js` add a line like this:

```
exports.Global = Global;
```

Then remove that line from `index.html`. That should do it.

I am guessing that you are not familiar with CommonJS style modules. Modules do not share global variables. Everything (except for a few properties supplied by the commonJS implementation) needs to be required before it can be used. Also, if you want to expose values between modules, you need to use `exports` keyword.

There is a much more detailed explanation on the [CommonJS site](http://www.commonjs.org/).